# When to make pointer point to a struct on the heap vs on the stack?

Tags: c, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct foo {
    char* text;
    int num;
} foo;

int main(void) {

    foo* a = malloc(sizeof(foo));
    a->text = "Something";
    a->num = 4;
    printf("%s %d\n", a->text, a->num);

    foo b;
    b.text = "Something";
    b.num = 4;
    foo* c = &b;
    printf("%s %d", c->text, c->num);

    return 0;
}
```

Both print the exact same thing. The only difference between `foo* a` and `foo* c` is where each one points to. Which one should be preferred? I usually see `malloc()` more but I don't understand why.

Comment: It depends on the application.

Comment: when defined from `main` it doesn't matter much because variables from `main` have a longer lifespan than any other ones in subroutines (if the data is too big, you may exhaust the stack, though)

Comment: Use the stack if you only intend to use the value in the scope of the function, or if you're copying the value somewhere else. Use heap if you intend to return a pointer to memory you allocated from the function, and you expect to `free()` it elsewhere after the block of memory is done being used. FWIW, heap memory takes more cycles to read and write than stack memory does, since it accesses to external RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should `malloc()` only for bigger data. You should consider that `malloc()` needs more time because it must find search for a data block in the heap and reserve it. If you use the struct on stack this is not necessary. So it really depends on what you are doing.

**Edit:** Also you should think of the scope of the variable. If the struct is needed only within the function I would prefer the stack.

Comment: Although I've closed the question as a dupe, +1 for pointing out the scope / lifetime consideration.  The answers to the dupe target only touch lightly on that, but it is one of the major reasons.

Comment: Thanks for that.

Comment: Why would it be better to use the stack when it is only needed within the function?

Comment: Because it's faster than using the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Heap-allocated data is easier to share with others (i.e. across function boundaries), especially when the function that creates an object needs to have it usable when that function has exited. This is not possible with non-heap data (except when using `static` but that creates problems too), which can be rather limiting.